# TS: Is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have read a lot of similar questions and documentation on generics, but can't get my head around TS generics constraints.

Let's say I have an interface, and I want to restrict my function to work with this *and capable* interfaces, like so:

```
interface PageProps {
  foo: string;
}

const createGenericPageProps = <T extends PageProps>(): T => {
  return {
    foo: 'asd',
  };
};
```

This does not work and produce an error:

```
Type '{ foo: string; }' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  '{ foo: string; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'PageProps'.
```

On other hand, same function is ok to return concrete type:

```
const createConcretePageProps = (): PageProps => {
  return {
    foo: 'asd',
  };
};
```

TS Playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=3&pln=11&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApwOYVVA9gBwGdkBvAWAChlkZdcAuZQsKUDAbkoF9LKFcQzZAigQ4kAOIQQ0YAnRYcBYgF5kAHgAqyCAA9IIACbEF2PEQB8ACgCUjbSoulK1UWACuUEM6rUadRgByOEJDQIAaF2QuTgoY3gp+QTBhUXEIAGEBEQhIUyUiZDVbRnzzVSdyXzdPbyq-fwZkYNCIqPi49iA

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr if you deal with object generics you can only obtain their values externally from function arguments, you can't make them from nothing

like,

```
interface PageProps {
  foo: string;
}

const createGenericPageProps = <T extends PageProps>(tMaker: (p: PageProps) => T): T => {
  return tMaker({
    foo: 'asd',
  });
};
```